# Choosing number of factors in PLSR

Tags: regression, factor-analysis, partial-least-squares

Im confused about how many factors I should choose for my prediction model. I am using Unscrambler X to do PLSR. Unscrambler is supposed to suggest the optimal number of factors. It suggests 4 factors in my case. With 4 I get an RMSEP value of 0.2436. But with 7 I get RMSEP 0.1664. Why have 4 and not 7? anything else I need to look at, not only RMSEP?

Comment: Is the RMSEP you are quoting an out-of-sample measure (i.e. computed on data not used to fit the model, such as might be achieved by split sampling or crossvalidation)? If not you shouldn't trust these values and as you've seen a more complex model will have a lower RMSEP as it is more free to adapt to features of your particular sample from the population. I'm not familiar with *Unscrambler* so can't comment on those specifics.

Comment: Thanks for comment! Yes, I used leave-one-out cross validation. But why is complexity reduced when having few factors? I understand in the analysis aspect of it. Much easier to determine correlations in loadings plot with 2 factors having 100% of the variance than 5. But does it matter in the prediction model? I mean its still regression coeffisients for all the variables no matter how many factors I use so the complexity stays the same(?)

Comment: As the number of factors increases the "regularization" decreases hence the chance of overfitting increases. For instance, using all factors is basically equivalent to OLS. The referred complexity here (for PLS) is the how much covariance between X and Y is account for. Some of this covariance is noise and using only a few factors helps to avoid modeling of this noise.